# Mute microphone programatically in Phonegap / Sencha Touch

Tags: android, cordova, sencha-touch

I am trying to build an android application using phonegap and sencha touch , in my application i want to mute the microphone whenever user calls , can anyone tell me is it possible to implement it in using these android web tools ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PhoneGap has no API to access the microphone as far as I know. You'll need to create a [PhoneGap plugin for android](http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/36753494/How%20to%20Create%20a%20PhoneGap%20Plugin%20for%20Android) that issues the following command on Android:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setMicrophoneMute(true);
```

Comment: so does it mean whatever native functions i need to access (which is not a part of phonegap) i have make a plugin for that ?

Comment: @Hunt Yes, that's the pitfall of using something like PhoneGap.